# Trying to run cURL from command line (xampp/windows environment)

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my Windows machine and have cURL enabled as this is shown within my phpinfo() document.

I am trying to run cURL directly from my command line - I understand how to add paths to the system environment but where is the cURL.exe located or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things completely different, in your PHP you can only use **curl** library described in this manual [PHP CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) 
**On Windows OS**, to use curl in command line you have to download and install/deploy curl package from this url [CURL Windows Command](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Answer (score 3):

cURL is a library.

PHP has bindings for it, and XAMPP comes with those.

XAMPP does not come with the command line utility that uses that library. You will need to install it separately.

The [cURL homepage](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) links to a Windows version.

Comment: @RiggsFolly — No, they want to use the standalone curl executable. That's why they mentioned curl.exe

Comment: Woops yes it looks like you are correct, beg pardon

Comment: Sorry i probably wasn't clear - i wish to use curl executable (without the PHP) I probably didn't phrase it the best

Comment: @Zabs No it was probably me not engaging brain before starting my computer